# Query to return multi-day items as daily items

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a schedule page that list events users have to participate to but I would like the events that span over many days to appear listed on each of those days. Probably a common issue :)

`SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY date` (and then looping the results and grouping them by day in PHP) only lists the multiday events only on their beginning day.

Is there a straight forward SQL query that would return a separate row for each day that one events spans to so I can get a result set like the one below for the scenario where event_id 3 spans between 21 and 23 of April?

```
event_id | date_starts | [eventually other columns...] 
2          2015-04-15
3          2015-04-21
3          2015-04-22 
3          2015-04-23
5          2015-04-28
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a calendar or numbers table.  If you know the longest event is three days, for instance, you could do:

```
select e.event_id, e.startdate + interval n.n day as thedate
from events e join
     (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2) n
    on e.startdate + interval n.n day <= e.enddate;
```

This will work well if the maximum number of days is not too big, so you can easily create the `n` subquery.

Comment: Can you explain a bit? Plus, I don't know the maximum number of days for events unless I query and calculate it first. Knowing the longest event is a requirement for your solution?